# modify `objects` to *always* return a subset of objects?

Tags: python, django

I have an `Events` table which contains various types of events. I care only about one of those types. As a result, *every query* I write begins with

```
Events.objects.filter(event_type="the_type").\
       etc(...).etc(...)`.
```

Obviously this is repetitive and easy to forget. Is there a way to use a custom `Manager` so that the `objects` attribute *always* returns a specific subset of the rows, without explicitly asking for it? Or any other way to restrict the model to specific subset of the rows??

Comment: You can write your own manager, and add it in the Events model, you can read it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/

you can also write somewhere in your code: events_qs = Events.objects.filter(event_type="the_type")

and start each query: events_qs.etc(...).etc(...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we can make a manager like:

```
from django.db import models

class EventManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(EventManager, self).get_queryset().filter(event_type="the_type")
```

and then add the manager to the `Event` class:

```
class Event(models.Model):

    # ...

    objects = EventManager()
```

Note however that some parts of Django will *not* use `.objects`, but [`._base_manager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/#django.db.models.Model._base_manager), and thus still return the entire set. Furthermore my own experience with overriding the `.objects` manager is that it turns out to cause a lot of harm, for example if you want to set an attribute of *all* events, then writing `Event.objects.all().update(foo='bar')` will only update the events with `the_type` as type, whereas the code suggests otherwise.

Personally I think it is better to construct a manager with a different name, that at least hints that something is filtered, for example:

```
class Event(models.Model):

    # ...

    all_events = models.Manager()
    type_events = EventManager()
```

here `Event.objects` no longer exist, but you write `Event.all_events`, or `Event.type_events`, and thus the code clearly hints what subset you take.